# Calculate the median to 4 decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, common-table-expression, median

Given a table, station, with one of its column, LAT_N. What is the median of LAT_N to 4 decimal places?

```
with newstation as (select lat_n from station order by lat_n asc)
select count(lat_n) as n 
case 
    when n%2!=0 then 
     Round((n+1)/2,4) 
    else 
       Round((n/2)+n/2+1)
end as median 
from newstation
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.